# Magento2 How can I remove My account functionality from entire site

Tags: magento2, customer-account

I need to remove My Account functionality from the entire site. I need only guest user.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Interesting proposal. Lots of template work. Basically hide links and buttons to create account / log into account in header and checkout. You could look into redirects on the account create controller. It's not config though. This would be bespoke theme work.

Comment: Yes currently I am removing 1 after another from theme

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the output for particular module by using below guide.
you can disable customer module output.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/config/disable-module-output.html

or you must need to remove all customer related things from frontend.

Thank you